# Android ImageButton issues, how to call methods and toasts with cumulative pressing

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton, android-image

I have a clown honking app. When the user presses the imagebutton that takes up the whole screen, it plays a mediaplayer sound that lasts for half a second.

I want it to play toasts that say HONK, HONK!!!, and HONK!!!!!!! randomly, as well as keep a counting variable that toasts AMAZING HONKS when that count reaches a (%10 == 0) and/or a (%100 == 0) statement.

I added an on touch and an onbuttonlistener, and Im geting nowhere with my count. I also want to have the imagebutton take the whole screen and have a textview on top of the imagebutton...

Posting my MAIN and my XML:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

public void amazinghonks(View view)
{
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bikehorn);
    mp.start();
}

private SoundPool soundPool;
private int soundID;
private int soundID2;
boolean loaded = false;
boolean songloaded = false;
int honkcount = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.toptext);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    // Set the hardware buttons to control the music
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    // Load the sound
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });
    soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.bikehorn, 1);
    soundID2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.clown, 1);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "HONK!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {



    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Getting the user sound settings
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
        // Is the sound loaded already?
        if (loaded && (honkcount < 3)) {
            honkcount++;
            soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
            Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
        }

            if (songloaded && (honkcount > 10)) {
                honkcount = 0;
                soundPool.play(soundID2, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
            }




    }
    return false;
}




public void addListenerOnButton() {

    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            double randomnumber = Math.random()*101;
       //WILL HAVE THREE KINDS OF HONKS!     
            if(randomnumber < 33)
            {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "HONK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            if((randomnumber < 66)&&(randomnumber > 33))
            {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "HONK!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if((randomnumber < 101)&&(randomnumber > 66))
            {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "HONK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

    });

}

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toptext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#303030"
    android:text="@string/toptext"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#33B5E5" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.62"
    android:contentDescription="@string/honktext"
    android:onClick="amazinghonks"
    android:src="@drawable/big_clown" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you never call your `addListenerOnButton()` method, so it's never executed. Try calling it in your `onCreate()` method.

For the `ImageButton` to take up the whole view, with a `TextView` on top (as in greater z-index, right?) You'd want to use a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`. And try setting the height of your `ImageButton` to "fill_parent" and not 0dip. A height of 0 will effectively hide it, making it impossible to click.